# formatting a Complex PHP Array returned by SOAP Call

Tags: php, soap, multidimensional-array, nusoap

I'm currently working with a webserivce using nusoap to build my method calls,
my problem is the array which is returned and how to format this in a manner which is useable, other projects I've worked on returns s much simpler structured xml file, were i could use $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile); to build and sort my arrays,

this is the nusoap call

```
$PickUpDateTime='2011-03-17T09:00:00';
$ReturnDateTime='2011-03-21T09:00:00';
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl="Srvc.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl'); 
$param = array('OTA_VehAvailRateRQ' => 
        array('VehAvailRQCore' => 
           array('VehRentalCore' => 
            array('PickUpDateTime'=>$PickUpDateTime,
                'ReturnDateTime'=>$ReturnDateTime,
                'PickUpLocation' => array('LocationCode' =>$location),
                'ReturnLocation' => array('LocationCode' =>$location)
            )//PickUpDateTime, ReturnDateTime, PickUpLocation, ReturnLocation
               )//VehRentalCore
        )//VehAvailRQCore
        ); //OTA_VehAvailRateRQ

// LOAD OUR VARIABLE WITH THE RETURN ARRAY
$res = $client->call('GetVehAvailRate', $param);
```

nomally at this point I would use the simplexml_load_string(); but this dosnt seem to work with this call, doing a dump of $res produces.. ( Lots of data is missing due to the posting limit... but once the array gets to the Vehicle theres a lor more arrays in there...

```
    Array
(
    [Success] => 
    [VehAvailRSCore] => Array
        (
            [VehRentalCore] => Array
                (
                    [PickUpLocation] => Array
                        (
                            [!LocationCode] => LOCATIONNAME
                        )

                    [ReturnLocation] => Array
                        (
                            [!LocationCode] => LOCATIONNAME
                        )

                    [!PickUpDateTime] => 2011-03-23T09:00:00
                    [!ReturnDateTime] => 2011-03-31T09:00:00
                )

            [VehVendorAvails] => Array
                (
                    [VehVendorAvail] => Array
                        (
                            [Vendor] => Array
                                (
                                    [!Code] => AD
                                )

                            [VehAvails] => Array
                                (
                                    [VehAvail] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [VehAvailCore] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Vehicle] => Array ()
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [VehAvailCore] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Vehicle] => Array ()
                                                        )
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [VehAvailCore] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Vehicle] => Array()
                                                        )
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [VehAvailCore] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Vehicle] => Array()

                                                        )
                                        )

                                )

                            [Info] => Array
                                (
                                    [LocationDetails] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [!EchoToken] => xxxxxxxx
    [!TimeStamp] => 2011-03-18T11:35:19.165125-04:00
    [!Target] => xxxxx
    [!Version] => xxxxxx
    [!TransactionIdentifier] => xxx
)
```

When trying to loop through the multiarray using a foreach loop is proving a little more harder than first thought...

now when Im trying to access each element using a foreach loop, I'm having to use the literal calls, ie: $res['VehAvailRSCore']; also those exclamation marks i havent came across before either: ie !LocationCode, normaly this would be just $res->LocationCode

So my question is this... how can i use this array to my advantage? 
just so i can call each array element, and possibly add this / these values to an other array so i can format my page better?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, nusoap is dead. Do not use it. Use PHP's built-in SOAP class instead.

Accessing the array values has to done with

```
$a['key1']['subkey']['subsubkey']['subsubkey']
```

- PHP itself provides no way apart from that.

Comment: Hi cweiske, The use of nusoap was sudgested by the company hosting the webserive, I have since replaced the nusoap call with the PHP Soap call, the Results are a little better, theres no exclamation mark at the start of the array values, but still im left with this huge multi Array, and trying to loop through the info has been a nightmare.... :|

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post which code has worked for me..
I've changed out the call to the nusoap class, and replaced it with PHP SoapClass

```
$wsdl="..Srvc.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$param = array('OTA_VehAvailRateRQ' => 
           array('VehAvailRQCore' =>
             array('VehRentalCore' => 
               array('PickUpDateTime'=>$PickUpDateTime,
                     'ReturnDateTime'=>$ReturnDateTime,
                     'PickUpLocation' => array('LocationCode' =>$location),
                     'ReturnLocation' => array('LocationCode' =>$location)
                    )
             )//VehRentalCore
           )//VehAvailRQCore
         ); //OTA_VehAvailRateRQ
$res = $client->__soapCall('GetVehAvailRate', $param);
```

The return is now an Object, which wont display those horrid exclamation marks, 
to access each value, i used the non literal way,

```
foreach($res->subkey->subsubkey->subsubsubkey->subsubsubsubkey as $result) {
   echo "<div style='padding:10px; border:1px solid #ccc;'>";
   foreach($result as $value){
      $string = $value->subkey->subsubkey->subsubsubkey;
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($value);
      echo "</pre>";
   }
   echo "</div>";
}
```

Hope someone else can get use from it..
Thanks for your help :)